# How to Install flatpak on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, flatpak, gimp

GIMP 2.10 came out and I'm really excited to use it. The website suggests installing it with flatpak. According to flatpak's website, Linux Mint 18 and forward have it already installed, but as I'm using Linux Mint 17.1, I do not have it.

I tried following the Ubuntu installation requirements for flatpak, as well as some [other](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=229637) forums, which suggest entering the following into the terminal:

```
apt add-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
apt update
apt install flatpak
```

After entering the last command, the terminal prints out:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flatpak
```

Any ideas on how I can install flatpak or GIMP 2.10 without using flatpak?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [repository you mentioned](https://launchpad.net/~alexlarsson/+archive/ubuntu/flatpak), there is no longer support for `trusty`, which is the base of your Linux Mint 17. That is the reason it can't find your `flatpak` package.

If you were experienced a bit, I would suggest you to go ahead and upgrade to Linux Mint 18. Sadly, I suppose that is not your case.

Look at the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444257/126755) if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[The official page says](https://flatpak.org/setup/Linux%20Mint/):

> ### Flatpak support is built into Linux Mint 18.3 and newer—no setup required!
>
> If you are using an older version, [upgrade to Linux Mint 18.3](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3462).

I guess there is nothing I can add here. Just upgrade…

It is the only “clean” and secure way. You cannot stay on this old system, anyway, in all future.